# Nested stored procedures chain

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nested

I have this SQL Server with a lot of stored procedures spread across all databases and 
I'm looking for a way to find the how those nested stored procedures are chained with each other, so basically to see which stored procedure is running which.

Wonder if anyone who had the same problem and found a way to get such information in some painless way rather than opening each stored procedure and checking what other stored procedure it is running.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Approach #1

Right click on the table name and select "View Dependencies" as shown below we are looking at dependencies for the Employee table.

[image]

---

### Approach #2

```
SELECT 
        routine_name, 
        routine_type 

FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES

WHERE   ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%Your Object Name%'
```

---

### Approach #3

```
EXEC sp_depends 'Your Object Name'
```

---

### Approach #4

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('Your Object Name', 'OBJECT');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what information you want, you can query the sys.sql_expression_dependencies catalog view or use the sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities or sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities dynamic management functions.

Information on these, including various examples of SQL queries for both direct and indirect dependencies (chained dependencies) can be found here: [Reporting SQL Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677168.aspx).